# How to enable auto update for embedded plugins

Tags: plugin-development, automatic-updates

I'm working on a plugin that will support my custom theme. I've embedded some commercial plugins like elementor free and pro elements, but I've noticed that I'm unable to let auto update them if needed and also in preview mode elementor will not apply style to buttons like I see on the visual editor of the pages.

This is the constructor of my plugin

```php
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'load_theme_assets']);
        add_action('after_setup_theme', [$this, 'extend_theme_support']);
        add_action('init', [$this, 'setup_my_carousel']);
        add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'remove_menu_pages']);

        //
        require_once __DIR__ . '/elementor/elementor.php';
        require_once __DIR__ . '/pro-elements/pro-elements.php';
        require_once __DIR__ . '/my-board/my-board.php';
        require_once __DIR__ . '/my-seo/my-seo.php';
    }
```

I don't think the problem about preview of some elementor free widgets is caused from the way I'm embedding it, but not sure.
Is there any way to enable update for the embedded plugins?

Comment: you shouldn't bundle plugins inside other plugins like that, especially since updating your own plugin would destroy its folder and replace it with the new version. It's better practice to check for the presence of those plugins and disable functionality or exit early with an admin notice warning that they need to be installed. You should expect to encounter more issues like the elementor widget preview if you continue.

Comment: Can you provide an example of correct inplementation please?

Comment: Look at the `is_plugin_active` API